# When I hash string using sha-256 and compare it with online hash tools the results are different using java 8?

Tags: java, data-integrity, message-digest

When I trying to hash string in java 8 using `SHA-256` with different library such as MessageDigest, guava and apache the result is not same in the online tool here what I do:

```
public static String hash(String planText){
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hashed = messageDigest.digest(planText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String encodeHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashed);
    return encodeHash;
 }
```

for this String:

```
<root>
   <test>
      abc
   </test>
</root>
```

the return of this function is  `lPJDgg2R+x+/H6qHZ59lACAemdF7/JFeQex+otuQ7Xk=`.
for the online tool is `c8awdfivV+DgU43KR5uK8xEh5ginLGATnJdyfs1573w=` [Hash generator tool](https://www.online-convert.com/result#j=e572a588-94c0-4ca4-95be-726d77f5cd70).

the benefit of using hashing to achieve  data integrity, so there something I miss to do?

Comment: Your string contains a lot of whitespace, you probably have an additional newline in one and not the other.

Comment: It is xml saved as string, also when I remove the spaces is still same issue.

Comment: Your linked site does not even document what hash algorithm is used.

Comment: You can visit the home page and choose the hash algorithm sha-256, that's what I already do.

Comment: @albaradev I was able to generate same hash using your program. It seems online tool is trimming string before it works with it.
https://postimg.cc/ZW5vjJDR

Comment: thanks, it work with me, so all of this is all about the spaces in string cause I work to hash a e-invoice and the e-invoice must be xml format. I need to delete all the spaces ```String.replaceAll("\\s+ ","");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to address this would be to parse string line by line,
then remove indents, whitespaces and also trim(if required).

I got consistent output with this
[image]

[image]